# Save as csv file in javascript

Tags: javascript, csv, export-to-csv, download, save-as

I am still a beginner in javascript and still training , I make a code that computes sunrise, sunset, ,noon & midnight times.

I could everything make w/o problems (even it is not professional) and with help of many topics in StackOverflow.

I can use `document.write()` or `console.log()` to use my result.

I would know, how to save my result as csv file instead of displaying my result with `document.write()`

My displayed result is already in csv format:

> 01/01/yyyy,06:00:00,12:00:00,18:00:00,00:00:00 ......
>   31/12/yyyy,06:00:00,12:00:00,18:00:00,00:00:00

Conclusion: how to save my result as csv file, and please with explaining.

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html>
    <head>
        <title>Sunrise and Sunset</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form>
    Latitude: <input id='lat' value='52.0'>
    <br>
    Longitude: <input id='lon' value='10.0'>
    <br>
    Elevation: <input id='elv' value='0.0'>
    <br><br>
    Year: <input id='yr' value='2000'>
    <br>
    Time zone: <input id='tz' value='1.0'>
    <br>
    <button id='btn' onclick='rechner();'>
    Get your data
    </button>
    </body> </html>
```

Javascript:

```
//-------Degrees to radians------//
function toRad(angle){

    return angle*Math.PI/180;
};

//------Radians to degrees-------//
function toDeg(angle){

    return angle*180/Math.PI;
};

//---------Main function-------//

function rechner(){
    var lat,lon,elv,year,tzone;

lat = parseFloat(document.getElementById('lat').value);
lon = parseFloat(document.getElementById('lon').value);
elv = parseFloat(document.getElementById('elv').value);

year = parseInt(document.getElementById('yr').value);
tzone = parseFloat(document.getElementById('tz').value);

    var dip_angle = 0.0347*Math.sqrt(elv);
//dip angle for sunrise and sunset accounting for elevation of the location, it is here in degrees expressed

    var date = new Date(year,0,1,12);
    var time = date.getTime();
    var julian_date = (time / 86400000) - (date.getTimezoneOffset()/1440) + 2440587.5;
    var d = julian_date - 2451545.0;

var yr = date.getFullYear();
// get year from the date 01/01/YYYY


    for(var i=0; i<=((yr%4)==0 ? 365 : 364); i++){

    var D = d+i;

//------Solar approximate coordinates----//

    var g = ((357.529 + 0.98560028*D)+360)%360;
//Mean anomaly of the Sun

    var q = ((280.459 + 0.98564736*D)+360)%360;
//Mean longitude of the Sun

    var L = ((q + 1.915*Math.sin(toRad(g)) + 0.020*Math.sin(toRad(2*g)))+360)%360;
//Geocentric apparent ecliptic longitude of the Sun (adjusted for aberration)

    var e = 23.439 - 0.00000036*D;
//Mean obliquity of the ecliptic

    var ra = ((toDeg(Math.atan2(Math.cos(toRad(e))*Math.sin(toRad(L)),Math.cos(toRad(L)))))+360)%360;
// Right ascension in deg

    var dec = toDeg(Math.asin(Math.sin(toRad(e))*Math.sin(toRad(L))));
// Declination in deg

    var eqt = (((q - ra)/15)+24)%24
//equation of time, in hrs

    var R = 1.00014 - 0.01671*Math.cos(toRad(g)) - 0.00014*Math.cos(toRad(2*g));
// Distance Sun-Earth in AU

    var SD = 0.2666/R;
// Semi-diameter of sun in degrees

//---function calculates timestamp from noon to the wanted angle under horizon--//

function timeTodip (angle){
    return 1/15*toDeg(Math.acos((-Math.sin(toRad(angle))-Math.sin(toRad (lat))*Math.sin(toRad(dec)))/(Math.cos(toRad(lat))*Math.cos(toRad(dec)))));
};

//function renders hh.hhh in range [0,24]
    function rendHr(y){
if(y>=0 && y<=24){return y;}
else if(y>24){return y%24;}
else{return y%24 + 24}
    };

//---function converts hh.hhhh to hh:mm:ss
    function hhToHMS(nbr){
var decimalTimeString = nbr;
var n = new Date(0,0);
n.setSeconds(+decimalTimeString * 60 * 60);
return n.toTimeString().slice(0, 8)
};

//---function gets date as DD/MM/YYYY---//

function convertDate(inputFormat) {
  function pad(s) { return (s < 10) ? '0' + s : s; }
  var z = new Date(inputFormat);
  return [pad(z.getDate()), pad(z.getMonth()+1), z.getFullYear()].join('/');
};

var noon = rendHr(12 + tzone - lon/15 - eqt); //noon time in format hh.hhhh


//--------Sunrise and sunset calc--------//

var sunrise = noon - timeTodip(0.833+dip_angle); //sunrise
var sunset = noon + timeTodip(0.833+dip_angle); //sunset

var mid = (24-rendHr(sunset-sunrise))/2 + sunset; //solar midnight

var nbrDay= new Date((10957+(julian_date - 2451545.0)+i)*86400000);

document.write(convertDate(nbrDay)+','+hhToHMS(sunrise)+','+hhToHMS(noon)+','+hhToHMS(sunset)+','+hhToHMS(mid)+'<br>');

    };
};
```

thanks for any help

**Edit**:
[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8mkpoc31/)

[js linter says it's good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIgHa.jpg)

Comment: For starters never use `document.write()`

Comment: you mean, how to present it as a downloadable file to the client? or how to save it to your server.

Comment: the client should click e.g. a button then it is downloaded as csv instead of being displayed in browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include this handy "saveAs" function somewhere in your document.

```
function saveAs(text, filename){
  var pom = document.createElement('a');
  pom.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=urf-8,'+encodeURIComponent(text));
  pom.setAttribute('download', filename);
  pom.click();
};
```

And then use it:

```
saveAs(myCSVString, "data.csv");
```

Comment: should the function saveAs(text,filename) be inside my function untill it save the whole list of data generated by for-loop? and directly writing what is between document.write() instead of myCSVString?

Comment: Where you put that function is up to you. If you would like to scope it within your current `rechner` function you may. And if you're concerned about polluting the global scope, then that would be preferable. But if you are likely to want to reuse this function in another part of your application then placing it outside of your `rechner` function so it is globally accessible might be more desirable.

Comment: You have many javascript errors that are not related to this question or the supplied function. Please run your javascript through a linter.

Comment: I run normally the code w/o problem wi dcoder app and tested it by linter... everything is ok... result is as expected.. only I wanted to save the result as csv file instead of displaying in webpage... I added a link of screenshot for jslinter validation

Comment: The code at that fiddle is NOT ok. There are JavaScript errors that will need to be cleaned up.

Comment: thanks you, that was ok ... but could you recommend sites where I can inform about that?! Blob or to crreate a function like yours that can save as ?!!

Comment: I wrote the function myself. You can see the gist here https://gist.github.com/dustinpoissant/a3d98b328c1c271e09f17111e0fe64f0